# IOS: problem to synchronize nsarray with string

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, text-files

I have a NSArray in this way

```
myArray[0] = [string1, string2, string3, string4, mySecondArray, string5]; (at 0 position)
```

I write this array inside a txt file in this way

```
NSString *outputString = @"";

for (int i = 0; i< myArray.count; i++){

    outputString =  [outputString stringByAppendingString:[[[myArray objectAtIndex:i ] componentsJoinedByString:@"#"] stringByAppendingString:@";"]];
}

NSLog(@"string to write = %@", outputString);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Text.txt"];
NSError *error;

[outputString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

then the result of NSLog is = (position 0 of myArray) (mySecond array is empty)

```
one#two#three#four#(
)#five;
```

I want to know:

- Why the array wrap?
- When I'll go to read this string how can I know that it's mySecondArray?

Answer (score 0):

When you message `componentsJoinedByString:` on an `NSArray` object, it calls `description` on each of its objects and concatenates them in order. For `NSString` objects, they are the strings themselves. The array wraps because of the way the `description` method has been implemented.

As for identifying the array while you are reading the string back, I don't think it is possible. You should consider writing the array to the file rather i.e.

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

or

```
[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

depending on the requirement. This way you will be able to read the elements back properly.